# Help Solving for $318.45 = 288.45*e^\frac{-t}{4.5} + 44.1t$ without graphing

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm doing a simple problem that involves an object with mass being thrown from a building with air resistance and solving for the maximum height and the time when the ball hits the ground, assuming it does not hit the building.

$\ m = 0.15 kg$,
$\ v_o = 20 m/s$,
$\ y_o = 30m$,
$\ g = 9.8 m/s^2$,
Air resistance $=\frac{-1}{30}v $

$\ m\frac{dv}{dt}=-mg - \frac{v}{30} $

I solved for both the velocity and position equations:

$\ v(t) = (v_o +30gm)e^\frac{-t}{30m}-30gm$

$\ y(t)= -30m(v_o + 30gm)e^\frac{-t}{30m} - 30gmt + 30m(v_o + 30gm) + y_o$

I then solved for the maximum height by finding the time when the velocity is zero, $\ t \approx 1.683 sec$, then plugged this number into the height which resulted in $\ y(1.683) \approx 45.783 m$

To find when the ball hits the ground I set the position function equal to zero and tried to solve for time.

$\ 0= -30m(v_o + 30gm)e^\frac{-t}{30m} - 30gmt + 30m(v_o + 30gm) + y_o$

$\ -30m(v_o + 30gm) -y_o = -30m(v_o+30gm)e^\frac{-t}{30m} - 30gmt $

Plugged in the constants

$\ -30*0.15(20+30*9.8*0.15)-30 = -30*0.15(20+30*9.8*0.15)e^\frac{-t}{30*0.15} - 30*9.5*0.15*t $

Simplfied to:

$\ 318.45 = 288.45e\frac{-t}{4.5}+44.1t$

I can solve this by graphing the two sides and finding the intersections, but my professor does not allow graphing calculators and was wondering if anyone knew how to calculate this without graphing it.

The answer is $\ t \approx 5.129 sec$

Comment: I appear to have messed up the last equation. It should be $\ 318.45 = 288.45e^\frac{-t}{4.5}+44.1t $

Comment: I got $$v(t)=-30mg+e^{-t/(3m)}C$$

Comment: When you calculate the initial value of $\ v(0) = v_0$, you get $\ v(t)=(v_o+30gm)e^\frac{-t}{30m}−30gm$

Comment: I'm guessing $\ e^\frac{-t}{3m}$ was a typo and supposed to be $\ e^\frac{-t}{30m}$

Comment: You can transform the equation so that you can solve it using the Lambert-W function.

Comment: No, the unit should be $e^{-t/30s}$, dividing a time by a length does not give a dimensionless number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using whole numbers, you are loking for the zero(s) of function
$$f(t)=\frac{5769}{20} e^{-2 t/9}+\frac{441 t}{10}-\frac{6369}{20}$$
$$f'(t)=\frac{441}{10}-\frac{641}{10} e^{-2 t/9}$$
$$f''(t)=\frac{641}{45} e^{-2 t/9} \qquad > 0 \qquad \forall t$$
The first derivative cancels at $$t_*=\frac{9}{2} \log \left(\frac{641}{441}\right)\approx 1.68293\implies f(t_*)=\frac{3969}{20} \log \left(\frac{641}{441}\right)-120 \approx-45.7828$$ and $f(0)=-30$. This makes the root to be larger than $t_*$.

To approximate the root, perform a Taylor expansion around $t*$; this should give, at least locally,
$$f(t)=\left(\frac{3969}{20} \log \left(\frac{641}{441}\right)-120\right)+\frac{49}{10}
   \left(t-\frac{9}{2} \log
   \left(\frac{641}{441}\right)\right)^2+O\left(\left(t-\frac{9}{2} \log
   \left(\frac{641}{441}\right)\right)^3\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, this gives as an approximation
$$t_0=\frac{1}{14} \left(\sqrt{6 \left(800-1323 \log
   \left(\frac{641}{441}\right)\right)}+63 \log \left(\frac{641}{441}\right)\right)\approx 4.73963$$

Now, use Newton method  and get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & t_n \\
 0 & 4.7396315 \\
 1 & 5.1453188 \\
 2 & 5.1285524 \\
 3 & 5.1285253
\end{array}
\right)$$

If you are ready to solve a cubic equation, add one extra term to the expansion and solve for $x$ the equation
$$x^3 f'''(t_*)+3 x^2 f''(t_*)+6 f(t_*)=0\qquad \text{where}\qquad x=t-t_*$$

Thsi would give, as another approximation, $t\approx 5.24569$.

Answer (score 0):

I would get everything on one side and divide by $288.45$ to get

$$e^{-t/4.5}+0.153t-1.1025 = 0.$$

Then use Newton's method to find zeros of the left side.  Let $f(t)$ be the left side.  Then the iteration is

$$x_{n+1} = x_{n} - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} = x_n -\frac{e^{-x_n/4.5}+0.153x_n-1.1025}{-e^{x_n/4.5}/4.5 +0.153}.$$

Looking at the equation, if I ignore the exponential, I see that $t\approx 7$ might not be a bad choice for $x_0$.  Applying the iteration once gives

$$x_1 = 5.307$$

Then $x_2= 5.106$ and $x_3 = 5.10296.$  Probably close enough.